# order by number of appearances in one column and query additional columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by, sql-order-by

```
SELECT  
    tbl_team.te_name, 
    tbl_player.pl_name, 
    tbl_scorer.sc_time
FROM            
    tbl_scorer
    INNER JOIN tbl_team on tbl_scorer.sID_team = tbl_team.pID_team
    INNER JOIN tbl_player on tbl_scorer.sID_player = tbl_player.pID_player
    INNER JOIN tbl_games on tbl_scorer.sID_game = tbl_games.pID_game
WHERE tbl_games.pID_game = 9
```

this gives me something like this

```
    +-------+----------+---+
    | TeamA | PlayerAA | 4 |
    +-------+----------+---+
    | TeamB | PlayerBA | 4 |
    +-------+----------+---+
    | TeamB | PlayerBB | 2 |
    +-------+----------+---+
    | TeamA | PlayerAA | 1 |
    +-------+----------+---+
    | TeamB | PlayerBB | 1 |
    +-------+----------+---+
```

what i want is to order this result by the number of appaerances of the team column like so

```
+-------+----------+---+
| TeamB | PlayerBA | 4 |
+-------+----------+---+
| TeamB | PlayerBB | 2 |
+-------+----------+---+
| TeamB | PlayerBB | 1 |
+-------+----------+---+
| TeamA | PlayerAA | 4 |
+-------+----------+---+
| TeamA | PlayerAA | 1 | 
+-------+----------+---+
```

I am able to query the number of rows grouped by the team name with

```
SELECT  
        tbl_team.te_name, 
        count(tbl_team.te_name)
    FROM            
        tbl_scorer
        INNER JOIN tbl_team on tbl_scorer.sID_team = tbl_team.pID_team
        INNER JOIN tbl_player on tbl_scorer.sID_player = tbl_player.pID_player
        INNER JOIN tbl_games on tbl_scorer.sID_game = tbl_games.pID_game
    WHERE tbl_games.pID_game = 9 group by tbl_team.te_name
```

but how to combine them to get the right order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  
    tbl_team.te_name, 
    tbl_player.pl_name, 
    tbl_scorer.sc_time
FROM            
    tbl_scorer
    INNER JOIN tbl_team on tbl_scorer.sID_team = tbl_team.pID_team
    INNER JOIN tbl_player on tbl_scorer.sID_player = tbl_player.pID_player
    INNER JOIN tbl_games on tbl_scorer.sID_game = tbl_games.pID_game
WHERE tbl_games.pID_game = 9)


SELECT a.*
FROM CTE a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(te_name) as Count_te FROM CTE b WHERE a.te_name = b.te_name) x
ORDER BY x.Count_te DESC, a.te_name, a.sc_time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

For the particular given data\

```
 select dh.* from 
(SELECT  
tbl_team.te_name, 
tbl_player.pl_name, 
tbl_scorer.sc_time
FROM            
tbl_scorer
INNER JOIN tbl_team on tbl_scorer.sID_team = tbl_team.pID_team
INNER JOIN tbl_player on tbl_scorer.sID_player = tbl_player.pID_player
INNER JOIN tbl_games on tbl_scorer.sID_game = tbl_games.pID_game
WHERE tbl_games.pID_game = 9) dh,    
(
SELECT  
tbl_team.te_name, 
count(tbl_team.te_name) rep
FROM            
tbl_scorer
INNER JOIN tbl_team on tbl_scorer.sID_team = tbl_team.pID_team
INNER JOIN tbl_player on tbl_scorer.sID_player = tbl_player.pID_player
INNER JOIN tbl_games on tbl_scorer.sID_game = tbl_games.pID_game
WHERE tbl_games.pID_game = 9
) xad
where dh.te_name=xad.te_name
order by xad.rep desc,dh.sc_time desc;
```

Comment: this will order the first column just by the alphabeth not by the amount of rows for one given entry for this query

Comment: Ok @Markus i didn't saw that result should be according to the no of times appearance ... now you can check the result ... as i edited my answer